# p4a php framework needs to reload cookies every time

Tags: php, zend-framework, firefox

I use a php framework called p4a, based on Zend.
However, every time I modify the source, I need to delete cookies on the browser and then reload the page.

Do you know if there is a shortcut or an extension for firefox or any other browser that clear cookies and then refresh the page?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you get the developer toolbar on Firefox you can quickly delete cookies, I'm not sure on how exactly you go about it, but there is definitely an option (It is described on the P4A sourceforge site) :) hope this helps =]

Answer (score 0):

You could always simply disable cookies in your browser.
There is a [developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) you can get that gives some shortcuts to disabling various parts or clearing cookes.

You can also do so globally from options, see [this page for details on how](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Enabling%20and%20disabling%20cookies)